# Empty array after subsciption

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, post, subscribe

Im trying to subscribe an array of products, but the result is an empty array.

**Before subscribe:**

[image]

**After subscribe:**

[image]

As far for my backend, everything works perfectly on postman and mongodb

**Routing:**

```js
orderRoute.route('/').post((req, res) =>{
    Product.find({_id: req.body._id})
    // .select('product')
    .populate('Product')
    .then(product => {
        if(!product){
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "product not found"
            });
        }
        const order = new OrderDetails({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            orderItems:product,
            // product_Quantity: req.body.product_Quantity,
            // product:req.body.productId,
            email: req.body.email,
            firstName:req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            address: req.body.address,
        });

        
        return order.save()
        })
 
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            
            return res.status(200).json({
                
                message: "Order was Created",
                
                order:result,
                request:{
                    type:"GET",
                    order_url: "http://localhost:5000/order/" + result._id
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error:err.message
            });
        });
    
    });
```

**Basically, my main goal is to achieve this:**

[image]
**Service:**

```js
CreateOrder(orderDetails:OrderDetails){
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/order`, orderDetails)
 }
```

**OrderDetails.ts:**

```js
import OrderItem from './OrderItem';
import Product from './Product';

export default class OrderDetails {
    firstName:String;
    lastName: String;
    email: String;
    phone: Number;
    address: String;
    country:String;
    city:String;
    orderItems:[{type: Product, ref: 'Product', required: true}];
    createdAt = new Date();
}
```

**Checkout.ts component:**

```js
 confirmOrder(){
    let orderDetails: any = {};
    orderDetails.firstName = this.checkOutForm.controls['firstName'].value;
    orderDetails.lastName = this.checkOutForm.controls['lastName'].value;
    orderDetails.phone = this.checkOutForm.controls['phone'].value;
    orderDetails.address = this.checkOutForm.controls['address'].value;
    orderDetails.country = this.checkOutForm.controls['country'].value;
    orderDetails.city = this.checkOutForm.controls['city'].value;
    orderDetails.email = this.checkOutForm.controls['email'].value;

    this.orderItems=[]
    for (let i in this.productAddedToCart) {
      this.orderItems.push({
        product_Name: this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Name,
        product_Quantity: this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Quantity,
        product_Price: this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Price,
        _id: this.productAddedToCart[i]._id,
        type: this.productAddedToCart[i].type,
        product_Description: this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Description,
        id: this.productAddedToCart[i].id

  
      });
      debugger
      
   }
   orderDetails.orderItems = this.orderItems

    debugger
    console.log("orderDetails:", orderDetails)

    this.orderService.CreateOrder(orderDetails).subscribe((data) => {
      debugger
      console.log("data is:", data)
      debugger
      this.globalResponse = data 
      console.log("globalResponse is:", this.globalResponse)
 
      debugger
    });
```

Perhaps the reason for the empty array is because the product _id isnt sent to the backend through the service? 
If so, how do I do that? Since the product _id is stored in orderItem array

Much appreciated!

Comment: Are the data also shown within this console log: console.log("globalResponse is:", this.globalResponse)? Can you give us the template code where you would like to display the data? Try to better explain where the data is not actually seen. You only said where the data is seen.

Comment: "global response" is the same as "data"... has personal details with an empty array of products.. also, the data is being saved to database the same way..